# How to mock window.google in a vue.js unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am trying to test a vue component that displays a google map

The google include script element is somewhere in a parent component and the component I am trying to test gets is reference to it globally:

```
const googleInstance = window.google
```

My alarm bells rang when I saw it is global, but its the code I have been given and I need to get my coverage higher!

The code in the component gets the instance here:

```
this.map = new googleInstance.maps.Map(mapElement, this.options)
```

I get many errors starting with:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
```

I have tried adding googleInstance and google to the mocks parameter when shallow mounting the wrapper

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Map, {
  mocks: {
    google: {
      maps: () => {}
    }
  }
})
```

Neither worked and I get the same response:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
```

I tried:

```
global.google = {
  maps: () => {}
}
```

That did not work either

Here is a simplified version of the map component that I am trying to test:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div refs="mapLayer" :id="mapName" class="mapLayer" />
</div>
</template>
<script>
const googleGlobal = window.google

export default {
  name: 'Map',
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.initMap()
  },
  methods: {
    initMap () {
      const mapElement = document.getElementById(this.mapName)
      this.map = new googleGlobal.maps.Map(mapElement)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The code has been refactored and previously the google instance came via the Vuex store and my tests worked

My other thought was to return googleInstance from a separate file, which I could then mock using jest, but ultimately that just moves the problem to another file that would still be untestable

How can I mock the values in my component or how could the code be refactored to be testable?

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing when you try the approach of setting `global.google`?

Comment: Thanks for responding @mgarcia
It just give the the same response as if the global was not there - its most frustrating!

Comment: So you are getting the same `TypeError` error when mocking `global.google`? Could you share more code of your component?

Comment: @mgarcia I have added a simplified version of the component as requested - the rest is mainly a search element and style. The point is that it had worked previously and my problem is mocking the constant for googleGlobal, which I don't think I can do or getting a mock function that will return it from window.google when it is called in the init function called when the component mounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `const googleGlobal = window.google` sentence is being executed before you introduce the mock in the test file.

Because of this, the `googleGlobal` constant is equal to `undefined`. A solution for this could be to define a method in your component that returns the global variable `google`, and obtain the reference by calling this method.

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Map',
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.initMap()
    },
    methods: {
        getGoogle() {
            return window.google
        },
        initMap () {
            const googleGlobal = this.getGoogle()
            const mapElement = document.getElementById(this.mapName)
            this.map = new googleGlobal.maps.Map(mapElement)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Then, in your test file you can mock `window.google` like:

```
window.google = {
    maps: { Map: function() {} }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By trying above solution i was getting the error

*> google.maps.map is not a constructor*

But this mocking worked.

```
    window.google = {
      maps: {
        Map: jest
          .fn()
          .mockImplementationOnce(success => Promise.resolve(success))
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Before defining the wrapper for your component, add a property to the global object

```
let google = <some object>;

Object.defineProperty(global, 'google', {
    value: google
})

const wrapper = ...
```